# Problem with transferring props to React Native Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to transfer data from parent RN Component to child.

***My parent RN Component:***

```
export default class ListOfUserPhotos extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    ...
}

render() {
     return this.state.photosKeysArray.map((photo, index) => {
            console.warn('photoData - ' + photo)
            // returns 'photoData - {photoValue}' - everything is OK here
            return <ListOfUserPhotos_ListView key = {index} 
                                              description = {photo.description}
                                              ...
                    />
        })
    }
    }
};
```

***My child RN Component:***

```
export default class ListOfUserPhotos_ListView extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <View style = {listOfUserPhotosStyle.container_list}>
            {console.warn('desc = ' + this.props.description)}
            // returns 'desc = undefined' - everything is BAD here

                ...

        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Before passing data to the child component I can console that data and see it there. But inside the component the props are undefined.

Can someone explain me what I did wrong? Or transferring data between RN Component should be implemented in other way?

Comment: looks like you are doing it right to me. Are you making an API call to retrieve the data?

Comment: I get data in parent component from Firebase database

Comment: Try to render your `ListOfUserPhotos_ListView` component conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

As you are retrieving the data asynchronously you should do the following to ensure that the component gets re-rendered.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // You need to set the state here to cause a re-render
    this.setState({
       photosKeysArray: firebase.response
    });
}

render() {
     const { photosKeysArray } = this.state;

     if(photosKeysArray.length === 0) {
       return <Text>Loading...</Text>
     }

     // this will be returned if above condition is not met
     return photosKeysArray.map((photo, index) => {
       return (
           <ListOfUserPhotos_ListView 
             key = {index} 
             description = {photo.description}
           />
         );
     })
};
```

Comment: Upvoted. Maybe `else` is not needed here since you are returning something in the `if` statement.

Comment: yeah, probably not needed. There would be a few ways to do this. You could also use `condition &&` but I think the answer above is probably the clearest, even if it is not how I would do it in practice

Comment: I agree with that, not talking about the logic. But without an else it would be cleaner :)